# Repetitive sequence (optimization)

Tags: python-3.x, list, optimization

I try to solve this problem:
initial list = [0, 1, 2, 2]
You get this sequence of numbers [0, 1, 2, 2] and you need to add every time the next natural number (so 3, 4, 5, etc.) n times, where n is the element of its index. For example, the next number to add is 3, and list[3] is 2, so you append [3] 2 times. New list will be: [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]. Then the index of 4 is 3, so you have to append 4 three times. The list will be [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4] and so on. ([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])

In order to solve this, I tried various approaches. I used recursion, but a recursive approach is very slow in this case. I tried as well the mathematical formula from OEIS (A055086) => a(n) = ceiling(2*sqrt(n+1)) - 2. The problem with the formula is that after 2 ** 20 it is too imprecise.

So, my next idea was to use memoization:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 2]
from itertools import repeat
def find(n):
    global lst
    print(lst[-1], n, flush = True)
    if len(lst) > n:
        return lst[n]
    for number in range(lst[-1]+1, n+1):
        lst += list(repeat(number, lst[number]))
        if len(lst) > n:
            return lst[n]
```

Now, this approach works until 2 ** 37, but after this is just timing out. The site where I try to implement my algorithm is (https://www.codewars.com/kata/5f134651bc9687000f8022c4/train/python). I don't ask for a solution, but for any hint on how to optimize my code.
I googled some similar problems and I found that in this case, I could use the total sum of the list, but is not very clear to me yet how could this help me.

Any help is welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

You can answer it iteratively like so:

```
def find(n):
    lst = [0,1,2,2]
    if n < 4:
        return lst[n]
    to_add = 3
    while n >= len(lst):
        for i in range(lst[to_add]):
            lst.append(to_add)
        to_add += 1
    return lst[n]
```

You could optimise for large n by breaking early in the `for` loop, and by keeping track of the list length separately, rather than calls to `len`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Definitely, I will remember this, didn't think about it. It's faster by doing so, but yet not fast enough.